# Is there anyway to check for new updates in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I'm making a `Node.js` app using `TypeScript`. I want to be able to check for a new `git push`. Is there any way to do it without exposing any ports?

Comment: What does git have to do with discord? What are you trying to do. And what does a domain have to do with this? You are presenting 3 different things without any reproducible issue, without code, without a real question.

Comment: @DanielW. I'm just giving the info. I don't know how to even start and that's why there isn't any code. I googled and went through stuff but everything I found needed me to expose the domain of the server that I'm running the bot on. I'm unable to do that and that's why I'm asking if there's any way to do it without exposing ports.

Comment: Are you checking if a `git push` has been done on the same server as the `Node.js` app runs on or if any system has pushed to a certain repo? My guess is that these kind of detail is why others find the question hard to answer. Most things can imagine what you want to do can be done with the GitHub API. You call the API to get the sha of the last commit, save it on your server, make another call after a certain time, and compare the sha. This should probably not require you to open anything not already open on a `Node.js` app.

Comment: @TheIceBear I'm checking if a `git push` has been made to a certain repo from any device. Thank you for the advice. Any idea how I can get started with the GH API?

Comment: Here is a wrapper for the api that you can use in Node https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-api

Comment: @TheIceBear Thank you, I'll try tomorrow.